# Razor pass special character to javascript function

Tags: javascript, razor, parameters, parameter-passing

In my input tag `onclick='login("@ViewBag.Title")'`

And `ViewBag.Title` contains []!@(*&$#^

How can I pass them to

```
function login(title){
    //dst
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I wanna use `<` character in razor and pass it to JavaScript object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ character converts to ASP.NET HTML encodes the output. 
This replaces reserved HTML characters with codes that enable the characters to be displayed as characters in a web page instead of being interpreted as HTML tags.

> Hence  []!@(*&$#^ will be encoded to []!@(*&$#^

You are safe to call Js function the way you are calling in your example.